# how to fix java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public int updateNotification(String notificationid, String isRead) {
        int result = 0;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataProviderConstants.NOTIFY_SENDER_ID, notificationid);
        values.put(DataProviderConstants.NOTIFY_STATUS, isRead);

        result = mContext.getContentResolver().update(
                DataProviderConstants.NOTIFICATION_TABLE_CONTENTURI, values,
                DataProviderConstants.NOTIFY_SENDER_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { notificationid });

        return result;
    }
```

This Code work fine and i am able Updated data in the table in Sqlite

```
public int UpdatetypeNotifcation(String notificationid, String notify_type) {
        int result1 = 0;
        ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
        value.put(DataProviderConstants.NOTIFY_SENDER_ID, notificationid);
        value.put(DataProviderConstants.NOTIFY_TYPE, notify_type);

        result1 = mContext.getContentResolver().update(
                DataProviderConstants.NOTIFICATION_TABLE_CONTENTURI, value,
                DataProviderConstants.NOTIFY_SENDER_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { notificationid });
        return result1;

    }
```

same code i am Using for Updated table with other value and method then am getting following Exception java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception  I dont know where am doing mistake please help

```
        result = mContext.getContentResolver().update(
                DataProviderConstants.NOTIFICATION_TABLE_CONTENTURI, values,
                DataProviderConstants.NOTIFY_SENDER_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { notificationid });

        return result;  this Line Exception is coming when i debug i don't know why this issue is coming please help
```

and suggest me : Below is Screen shot of Exception[image]

Comment: InvocationTargetException is just a wrapper. There's a root cause "caused by" exception in your logcat. Please include the full stacktrace in your question.

Comment: no Exception is there in Logcat

Comment: hello @laalto there man yaar no Exception is there in Logcat

Comment: @laalto there man what happen

Comment: The image you have shows a nested NullPointerException as the cause. Print its stacktrace (or just log the exception) to learn where the NPE is.